# Why is /bin a symbolic link to /usr/bin?

Tags: linux, symlink, directory-structure, fhs

According to the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s04.html) the `/bin` directory should contain utilities needed in single user mode. In practice, many Linux distributions make the directory a symbolic link to `/usr/bin`. Similarly, `/sbin` is nowadays often a symbolic link to /`usr/bin` as well.

What's the rationale behind the symlinks?

Comment: [TheCaseForTheUsrMerge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Short summary of the [page](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/) suggested by don_crissti:

Scattering utilities over different directories is no longer necessary and storing them all in `/usr/bin` simplifies the file system hierarchy. Also, the change makes Unix and Linux scripts / programmes more compatible.

Historically the utilities in the `/bin` and `/sbin` directories were used to mount the `usr` partition. This job is nowadays done by initramfs, and splitting the directories therefore no longer serves any purpose. The simplified file system hierarchy means, for instance, that distributions no longer need to fix paths to binaries (as they're now all in `/usr/bin`).

Comment: Well, if we no longer need to separate a `/usr` partition - why are we putting everything in /usr/bin rather than just moving everything out of `/usr` into `/`?

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to move everything out of `/usr`.

Comment: Umm, things only got moved _in_ to `/usr` because of storage constraints on ancient Unix machines. Nobody really needs the extra prefix. You said that storing executables in `/usr/bin` simplifies the hierarchy - well, storing them in `/bin` simplifies it even more.

Comment: @einpoklum There are many use cases where you'd want `/usr` on a separate partition, including (very common) mounting it as read-only.

Comment: @einpoklum at the bottom of the link given by don_crissti, about merging /usr into / : "This would make the separation between vendor-supplied OS resources and machine-specific even worse, thus making OS snapshots and network/container sharing of it much harder and non-atomic, and clutter the root file system with a multitude of new directories."

Comment: "This would make the separation between vendor-supplied OS resources and machine-specific even worse" - don't see why. `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are vendor-supplied OS resources. Machine-specific resource go into `/usr/local` or `/local` if you drop the `/usr` prefix. Or `/opt`.

Comment: It'll be easier and will require less changes to move small things (`/bin` and `/sbin`) while keeping a large thing (`/usr`) in place, than vice versa. Most source packages with autoconf/automake will have default installation target directories in the form of `$PREFIX/(bin|lib|man|share|sbin)`; making executables go into `/bin` or `/sbin` would increase complexity, while falling back to the default pattern (or keeping an existing one) will minimize it.